# Shouldn't the "recent declined flags" warning go away after clicking the link to review your flag history?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, declined-flags

Every time I am currently flagging a post on Ask Ubuntu, I see this warning:

> Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please review them before flagging this post!

I understand it is caused by the two declined flags 5 and 6 days ago (>10% of those flags reviewed within the last week), after which I already cast over 10 helpful flags again.

However, as I understand it, this warning's purpose is to make people review their flagging history to find out why a flag of them got declined and learn from that. I clicked this link about 5 times now already, but there were always only the same two recently declined flags.

Shouldn't the warning disappear after it fulfilled its purpose and the user clicked on the flag history link?

It's very annoying and confusing that the warning keeps coming up every time because I then have to check my flag history again to make sure it is not a new flag that got declined.

Comment: Problem is, SE can't possibly know you actually reviewed your flag history. You can click the link, leave the page open for whole day, yet not read even a single letter in there. So they take the safe path. That said, I would go for a small checkbox labelled "I reviewed my rejected flags", which after clicking it the message will go away.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Your argument sounds reasonable. However, if you put that checkbox at the top of the page, the same argument applies (just click the checkbox without reading). What about a checkbox right below every recently declined flag entry which is responsible for the warning? That way you make sure the user at least saw which of their flags got declined.

Comment: The position doesn't matter, if someone is inclined to review their flags they will, if they are not they won't, even if it is at the bottom.

Comment: @Byte Not a bad idea, but sounds too complex. As for same argument applies of course, but by having the user make an explicit action of ticking the checkbox (and not just have the message go away by itself after only viewing a page) is kind of saying "If you'll get flag banned now, it's totally your fault, don't be surprised".

Comment: I have the same thing happen and it's annoying because I'm not sure if it's a NEW flag that was declined or the same flag. It's stressful, since I constantly feel like I'm about to be flag banned.

Answer (score 3):

It's the way that it is because many folks flag large swaths of posts hoping that some of 'em will stick.

Hence, even if we took the fact that someone subsequently had 10 flags approved after a bunch were declined, it could very well have been that those 10 were the only helpful flags out of the bunch. We don't track what routes people load in a manner that's conducive to dismissing something like that, so our options here are pretty limited.

I'm not opposed to showing it only a fixed number of times, but I'm not entirely certain how much work that would be.

Comment: I propose: only show the dialog iff the warning threshold has been met AND there has been a declined flag since that user last checked his flag history.